# SWT editable text field on canvas

Tags: java, canvas, widget, swt, textfield

Is it possible to have an editable text field within a canvas, and if so, how? I'd prefer if the users could edit the text field directly by selecting it and inputting text in. They should also be able to edit the text.

Comment: Canvas is really intended for drawing graphics on directly rather than having child controls. If you are not drawing on the Canvas use Composite instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out you just have to use the canvas as the widget's (the text field) parent. Like this:

```
new Text(canvas, SWT.BORDER).setBounds(100, 100, 80, 80);
```